# Can we use global variables in triggers to get informations

Tags: apex, trigger, global-variables

Can we use global variables like $Profile, $setup, $Label in apex triggers and apex Code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables staring from prefix "$" are intended for visualforce page and formula function. You cannot make use of them by `$profile` or `$Label`.

`$Label` used to show pre-defined custom label on visualforce page. In trigger you can access `Label` as:

```
String myLabel = Label.myCustomLabelName;
```

in Apex Class:

```
System.Label.myCustomLabelName
```

`$Profile` is used to get current user profile. In Apex code you can get a user profile as

```
Userinfo.getProfileId()
```

`$setup` is for accessing custom setting of hierarchy type. In Apex you can get custom setting as

```
NameOfCustomSetting__c cSetting = NameOfCustomSetting__c.getOrgDefaults(); // for hierarchy
```

Comment: I can get profile name using $Profile directly but using Userinfor i will get only profileId. To get profile name i will have to fire one additional query in database.

Comment: can we not use all the global variables using System keyword in Apex code? like System.profile.name

Comment: @PramodKumar You can query profile details by SOQL Ex: [Select Name from profile where id = userInfo.getProfileId]; . No, you cannot use `System.profile...` it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes you are right i can query but i want to avoid use of queries. Well thanks for reply

Comment: For common queries, consider a global static variable that is populated on first load (lazy load) to minimize queries. I've used this to great effect in my main work project; we issue just one query for the standard price book and reference this value through all of our code; we have trigger recursions up to 10 levels deep, yet never query the price book more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use global variables in trigger as you reference in formulas like using $ notation .These variables you can use in visualforce and formulas .

But these labels and custom settings and profiles you can refer in apex using Label.labelname for labels,there are custom setting methods and also profile you will have to query with knowing user id using Userinfo class .